# Why does: comparison of integers of different signs only happen sometimes?

Tags: c++

**SOLUTION:** Check if people have installed a custom compiler.

**Solution extended:** I had only compiled on servers and not locally on my machine, when I did that I could reproduce the answer of @A.K.
The compile on the servers are custome versions of g++ and clang++. Sorry for wasting peoples time :( The compilers will be delte and I will install the official once.

This is more a curiosity question than anything else.
When you do comparison of to numerical types, let us say `int` and `size_t` sometimes, this warning will appear: `error: comparison of integers of different signs:`, when using `-Wsign-compare` and `-Werror`, without `-Werror` is shows as a warning.

However, after starting working with a colleague I have noticed that it is not clear if the error will actually present itself. The reason I have noticed this is due to how we write `for-loops`. My colleagues' style:

`for (int i = 0; i < collection.size(); i++)`

and my style

`for (size_t i = 0; i < collection.size(); ++i)`

Where neither throws and error, if the collection is a standard collection (i.e vector, map) where `size_t` is the type of the returned size.
But if we go with a collection such as `pqxx::result` which has a size type `pqxx::result::size_type` or `unsigned long`. The `int i` approach results in the error.

This is weird to me as I would expect both cases to raise the error. Can someone explain why this is the case?
I have been able to reproduce this with both g++ and clang++

The full list of compile flags is `-std=c++17 -g -Wall -Wextra -O3` and the error is shown by clang and gcc to be due to `-Werror` and `-Wsign-compare` and the full error: `comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'unsigned long' [-Wsign-compare]`.

We both get this with g++ 9.3.1 20200408 and clang++ 9.0.1 provided, both from the Ubuntu package repo.

**Minimal working example:**

```cpp
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>

int main(void)
{
    srand(static_cast<uint32_t>(time(0)));
    std::vector<uint8_t> data(1024);
    std::generate(std::begin(data), std::end(data), rand);


    // No problem 
    for (size_t i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i)
    {}

    // No problem 
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i)
    {}

    unsigned long x = data.size();  
    // Problem
    for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i)
    {}
        
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: BAAHHHH, true @paulsm4 I always compile with -Werror therefor to me it is an error, I will adjust the question thank you :)

Comment: Why not use `for (auto && i : collection)` and side-step the issue entirely. Or, if you need the index, `for (decltype(collection.size()) i = 0; ...)`

Comment: You could do that as well @cdhowie old habits die hard I guess. But the `for-loops` are more examples. It was not meant as an it only occures here :)

Comment: The result of the increment expression (`i++` or `++i`) is not used, so for builtin types the two do exactly the same thing.

Comment: Are you really getting no warning in the code snipped you showed for the two loop? [I cannot reproduce..](https://godbolt.org/z/k3jjtc) Well, it could be that `data.size()` returns a custom object with overloaded `<` operators, but I don't think that would be valid. It could be that your libraries do `#pragma gcc ignore("-Wsign-compare")` somewhere in the code?

Comment: @KamilCuk check the edit I just made :| I had not thought about having to check for custom (BROKEN) compilers :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your issue with g++ 8.1.0. I always get an Error/Warning if I try to compare an int (which is signed by default) with size_t (which is unsigned by default). Which is to be expected since int is defined as signed by default: https://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types

The same happens (of course) if I use a class which uses unsigned long as size type. See the following example and the compiler output:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

class MyClass{
public:
  MyClass(){

  }
  MyClass(std::initializer_list<int> il): _size(std::distance(il.begin(), il.end())){
    _vals = new int[_size];
    std::copy(il.begin(), il.end(), _vals);
  }

  ~MyClass(){
    delete(_vals);
  }

  typedef unsigned long size_type ;

  int& operator[](size_type index){
    if (index >= _size) { 
        throw "Index out of range"; 
    } 
    return _vals[index]; 
  }

  size_type size(){
    return _size;
  }

private:
  int * _vals;
  size_type _size;
};

int main() {
  std::vector<int> collection = {1,2};
  MyClass my_class = {3,4};

  for(int i=0; i < collection.size(); i++){
    std::cout << collection[i] << std::endl;
  }

  for(size_t i=0; i < collection.size(); i++){
    std::cout << collection[i] << std::endl;
  }

  for(int i=0; i < my_class.size(); i++){
    std::cout << my_class[i] << std::endl;
  }

  for(MyClass::size_type i=0; i < my_class.size(); i++){
    std::cout << my_class[i] << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

which results in the following compiler output:

```
# g++ -Wall .\main.cpp -o main
.\main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
.\main.cpp:41:18: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: 'int' and 'std::vector<int>::size_type' {aka 'unsigned int'} [-Wsign-compare]
   for(int i=0; i < collection.size(); i++){
                ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
.\main.cpp:49:18: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: 'int' and 'MyClass::size_type' {aka 'long unsigned int'} [-Wsign-compare]
   for(int i=0; i < my_class.size(); i++){
                ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Maybe you are  compiling **without** `-Wsign-compare` and in your second example you are compiling **with** `-Wsign-compare`? Maybe you used `-Wno-sign-compare` or `-w` to disable the warning by mistake in your first example?

Comment: No both are with `-Wsign-compare` :) But okay, weird that it is not reproducible. We both can do it in our machies.

Comment: @LarsNielsen Could you please edit your question adding the exact  compiler version/flags you used and a [mre] demonstrating the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This can be the case when the implementation you're working with defines `collection::size_type` to something smaller than `std::size_t`. For example, if `collection::size_type` is defined to `unsigned short` comparing it with an `int` will not result in any error and comparing with `std::size_t` (which is usually at least the same width as a pointer) won't, neither, because each value an `unsigned short` can take can also be represented by an `int` and a `std::size_t`. Comparing with `pqxx::result::size_type` aka `unsigned long` will cause the error to show up because that comparison won't be safe for `int` (but seemingly for `std::size_t`). Thus an example case where this would be possible is

```cpp
// Pseudo code
typedef unsigned long std::size_t;
typedef unsigned short collection::size_type;
```

Admittedly, a constructed example, but still possible. I'd only expect something like this in embedded environments, though.

As A.K. points out in the other answer, it's also possible that the compiler flags differ, and this is IMHO more likely.

Comment: Thanks, I already checked mismatched compiler flags. That is not the case :)